# Is NSURLCache thread safe?

Tags: ios, multithreading, caching, nsurlcache, urlsession

I know `NSCache` is thread safe, however I can't find out any document mentioned that `NSURLCache` is thread safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally I'd take @bbum's stance on this, but in the case of `NSURLCache` disagree.

`NSURLConnection` is thread safe, in the sense that a given instance can be scheduled on a thread of your choosing (but don't try to schedule a single instance on multiple threads!)

By default, connections all interact with `+[NSURLCache sharedCache]`. Logically, this means either `NSURLCache` is itself thread safe, or offers a locking mechanism which clients can explicitly call themselves. Since the latter doesn't exist, I deduce `NSURLCache` is thread safe.

Would still like this to be documented officially, mind!

Comment: You can't safely deduce *anything* about thread safety.   It is an API contract and, unless the contract explicitly claims thread safety, then the details of the thread safety may change from release to release or platform to platform.

Answer (score 11):

Unless the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) explicitly says that `NSURLCache` is thread safe, then it is not thread safe.

(The docs say nothing about threads.  Therefore, not thread safe.)

And always check the docs again every now and then.  The thread safety rules have changed since I wrote this answer.

Comment: boss, this answer needs updating. Kasper's answer is official and valid

Answer (score 7):

Allow me to merge the two brilliant answers into a third one, now with a reference to the [updated documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlcache):

> **Thread Safety**
>
> In iOS 8 and later, and macOS 10.10 and later,
>   NSURLCache is thread safe.
>
> Although NSURLCache instance methods can safely be called from
>   multiple execution contexts at the same time, be aware that methods
>   like `cachedResponseForRequest:` and `storeCachedResponse:forRequest:`
>   have an unavoidable race condition when attempting to read or write
>   responses for the same request.
>
> Subclasses of NSURLCache must implement overridden methods in such a
>   thread safe manner.

That is, unless you explicitly call `cachedResponseForRequest:`, `storeCachedResponse:forRequest:` or other "methods alike", you'll be safe across threads. What "methods like" these are, seems to be an exercise left for the reader, but since you would hit an "unavoidable race condition" there is a good chance you will figure out eventually :-)